# How to write a canonical URL in Hugo?

Tags: hugo, canonical-link

I am trying to create a canonical URL for my web site by some tutorials in the web but I was not able to create a canonical URL. It always shows the current URL.

I have `layouts\partials\docs\inject\head.html`.

```html
{{- if isset .Params "canonical" -}}
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ .Params.baseURL }}" />
{{- else -}}
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ .Permalink }}" />
{{- end }}
```

And also I have `config.toml`.

```
baseURL = 'https://example.com/'
languageCode = 'en-us'
title = 'Hello world!'
theme = 'hugo-book'

[params]
  canonicalUrl = 'https://example.com/'
```

Bu it always shows the current link and not the canonical url. Like

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:1313/docs/hello/" />
```

while I expect to see:

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/docs/hello/" />
```

What is the proper way to show a canonical URL in Hugo?

Comment: I upvoted as I believe you asked the question excellently, where even though the answer was in a completely different "zone" I was able to understand, "mockup" mentally and answer. This seems very rare...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I believe you are running into the difference between running in the CLI "hugo" vs "hugo server".

Build your file with "hugo" and then check the canonical link in the files output.